# Fixed Charge Transportation Problem, only fixed cost (constant), non-minimal cost solution acceptable

Tags: graph-theory, integer-programming, network-flow

I want to solve the Fixed Charge Transportation Problem, although there is only a fixed cost for opening the route, no cost proportional to the edge weight. Each edge will have a maximum possible weight defined from the beginning.

The fixed cost d is 1 for every i,j and, at first, any solution, not only the one with minimal cost is acceptable, as it is possible to take cells forming a rectangle (in the matrix formulation) and redistribute quantities until one of them becomes zero, minimizing the cost. Getting the minimum cost is a hard problem in general and I may go without it.

What is the fastest algorithm to find a solution given that any cost is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the original problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  For each arc $(i,j)\in A$, let $u_{i,j}$ be the capacity of that arc, let nonnegative variable $x_{i,j}$ be the flow across that arc, and let binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether that arc is used.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{(i,j)\in A} y_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j)\in A} x_{i,j} &= s_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in A} x_{i,j} &= d_j &&\text{for all $j$}\\
x_{i,j} &\le u_{i,j} y_{i,j} &&\text{for all $(i,j)$}
\end{align}
To find a feasible solution, you can fix $y\equiv 1$ and solve the resulting transportation problem, using either a linear programming solver or some specialized network algorithm.  You can then post-process to set $y_{i,j}=1$ if $x_{i,j}>0$.

Comment: I see. So, it becomes a generic linear programming problem, right? Is there a link to an algorithm to solve this form? I will have to implement it. Or, maybe, a link to the network algorithm form?

Comment: SAS, my employer, provides both a [linear programming solver](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_007&docsetId=casmopt&docsetTarget=casmopt_lpsolver_toc.htm&locale=en) and a [network solver](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_007&docsetId=casmopt&docsetTarget=casmopt_networksolver_toc.htm&locale=en).

Comment: Sorry, the links are broken.